# Video gets cropped in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm fairly new to HTML and my mother just asked me to have a look at this code, as a video which she wants to play in 16:9 aspect ratio is strangely cropped/distorted.

Do you have any idea where I can alter the aspect ratio?

Thank you very much!

[image]

I tried to look at the "telio ticker crop.mov" but did not find anything about it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: [why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: is you `cover` or `fullscreen` class setting an aspect ration or fixed width/height? try removing those and see if you get the expected result (video will by default play at it's native aspect ratio)